# How to call a method in a jar file from Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, jar

In my project i have a requirement to call methods in a Jar file using VC++. Is there any way to call the methods inside the jar file from VC++. If sample code is there then it will help a lot.

Thanks in Advance!
Arun

Comment: Add a better description of the scenario you want to attempt. So you an show other people you have thought about the problem. Also you want C++ to call a method inside a Jar (similar to a zip) file? that makes no sense.

Comment: @C Johnson:  The question does make sense.  There are times when you have a Java library that you need to use the functions of, and you'd rather write the code in .Net because that's what you know.  I've got the same issue at work writing an application that interfaces to to a vendors SOAP interface.  The vendor provides a client library for the interface as a Jar file.  Rather than rewrite the client from scratch I was able to translate it to .Net using `ikvmc` and build my application in C#.

Answer (score 1):

IKVM.Net  ( http://www.ikvm.net ) is a .Net implementation of the Java libraries, which is not really what you want, but it includes a command-line tool called `ikvmc` (see http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Ikvmc) which will translate the java byte-code to .Net IL code, and produces a .Net assembly DLL.  I've used this successfully to translate a Java library to an assembly that I then included in a C# project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ as your target language then you must use JNI ( http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/). JNI defines an interface to exchange data and call methods from/to Java and native code. It is pretty straightforward to write a JNI wrapper to a class that contains methods returning and taking in input simple parameters ( that is native types, no collection , no arrays). When methods involves classes, collections, arrays and so on it can become quickly cumbersome to write the JNI wrapper by hand. This article provides a good overview: http://java.sys-con.com/node/45840. In this case you may evaluate a wrapper generator such as GIWS: http://www.scilab.org/products/other/giws.

If you are using the .NET environment as your target platform then IKVM is one option. However when we had to do this for a real project we preferred JNBridge and we had been quite successful with this (commercial) tool. We didn't evaluate IKVM for a business reason: our customer wanted only officially supported middleware.

Comment: Right! Use GIWS. Writing that by hand using JNI is a nightmare! (there are so many functions call to check, memory to be freed, etc)